# Building a game, need a language with strongly supported first class functions

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm building an educational game which, through it's modularity, allows for teaching students how to program. It's essentially a generic card game which can easily be modified.

The backbone of the game is supposed to be totally uneditable (at least in theory), so I need to build a "Card" type that allows for an anonymous function as it's action (even worse, or perhaps even more interesting, it needs an anonymous function that can have an arbitrary number of arguments).

I also need a strong GUI library, and it needs to be portable, and if at all possible it should be potentially be a web language. It should have extensive support for modularity, be object oriented, and hopefully be clear enough that it doesn't require an experienced programmer to understand the syntax. That's a lot of requirements, but I'm supposed to be detailed and I want a specific answer and why it'd be a good choice, so I should put as much information as possible I think. I have no real need for efficiency of the language, so low level languages are not necessary in this case, very high level languages will easily be fast enough.

Python isn't strong enough. Ruby may be but I'm not familiar enough with its features. Haskell and Scheme have the strongest support but aren't web languages and, so far as I know, don't have GUI libraries for the most part. C# may be reasonable, I'm not terribly familiar with its features, but I'm particularly worried about portability. If at all possible I'd like to avoid javascript, but if that really is the best option, I'll probably have to go in that direction.

Comment: portable to which platform specifically?

Comment: Help us understand the requirements: what about Python "isn't strong enough"?

Comment: Python has lousy, from my understanding from use and reading, lambda functions (I've used them extensively, though that doesn't mean I've been using them correctly). By portable I mean that it can be run on a mac, windows, and linux (embedded devices are not necessary candidates, I am assuming that the machine using this code is at least as powerful as a low end netbook).

Comment: C# has *sort of* first class functions. More like first and a half class. I think you can probably find a better choice.

Comment: What is it about C#'s support for first class functions / lambda functions that you think could have been done better?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid javascript?

Comment: @Breton Good question! Honest it really is just a personal bias against the language, though I'm starting to think that using a .NET language may be preferable b/c of associations with Silverlight

Comment: @Breton: the OP asked for a "strong GUI library" -- JavaScript's GUI-related functionality is pretty much limited to moving images or blocks around on the screen, showing/hiding them and changing colors or fonts or transparency.  I would consider that to be a very weak GUI library...

Comment: @RickNZ you clearly don't know very much about javascript if that's what you think.

Comment: @Michael you could use JScript.NET

Comment: @Breton Good suggestion! I will definitely look into JScript.NET

Comment: Michael: Python's lambda isn't as powerful as its def, but in practice, does it ever matter?  Most of the time lambda is sufficient, and even when you do need to name your function it'll still be more concise than C#.

Answer (score 6):

Javascript seems like a perfect choice for you - first class functions, portable, web-based, clear syntax, good library support. I know you're trying to avoid it, but I hope that once you've evaluated and rejected all other choices, that you'll give Javascript another chance.

Comment: Will try it. Thanks for the advice, I definitely appreciate it! I've been thinking that Javascript is going to be a necessity for a while, but have been trying to avoid it religiously... but it's pretty much a necessity in web programming these days, so I should learn it. Thanks again!

Comment: I would avoid JavaScript. It certainly doesn't have anything close to a "strong GUI library," as requested in the OP. Even worse, it's interpreted and not strongly typed, which makes for code that tends to be slow and buggy.

Comment: Hrm... the speed, as I mentioned, is not a big issue, but I will take that into consideration. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I haven't encountered a gui library any stronger than html+css. It's got it's problems, but it sure isn't anywhere near as ugly as win32/swing/cocoa/next/qt/wx/ etc. It's the worst possible gui library except for all the others. Re: slow and buggy; there may be buggy programs, and interpreters that are slow- But there are also well written programs, and fast interpreters. Buggyness and slowness don't have nearly as much to do with types and interpretation as implied. On buggyness and slowness, javascript is not much different from python, ruby, or java. In fact I think it's faster than ruby.

Comment: Javascript has one very strong advantage over all the other options though: Everyone has an interpreter already installed on their machine. This is a lot more important than most programmers seem to realise.

Comment: @Breton, I'm experience in HTML-CSS, but building an "Web 2.0" interface requires more than simply HTML and CSS. I definitely agree with your final sentiment though!

Comment: @Breton: no GUI library stronger than HTML+CSS? You're joking, right? Can you name a single modern video game with a GUI written in HTML and CSS? No 3-D support, no textures, no transforms, no timelining, etc

Comment: @RickNZ games don't use gui libraries for their menuing system. I think you're making a mistake conflating "graphics" with "guis". They are not the same thing.

Comment: As for "No 3-D support, no textures, no transforms, no timelining" all of those assertions are incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with Scheme, check out [DrScheme](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/drscheme/index.html) programming environment.
It has GUI support and it's ported to Windows, Linux and Macintosh.

Comment: I am quite familiar with Scheme, I am quite interested that someone would bring it up! Is there any way to make it webbased at the moment?

Comment: @Michael, in the documentation they mention how to build web applications, but I haven't tried it. See http://docs.plt-scheme.org/web-server/index.html

Comment: For educational games and GUI support. DrScheme is unbeatable!  +1

Comment: Interesting, another vote for Scheme... I must consider this more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [scala?](http://www.scala-lang.org/) It runs on the JVM, so you can leverage the Java swing libraries, and still have a strong functional language to code in.

Comment: Yes! I've actually considered Scala for a number of reasons in my education research. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with C# or perhaps F#, in the form of Silverlight. C# and F# both support anonymous functions (including lambda functions), and a variable number of arguments.

Silverlight apps can be delivered over the web, support a rich graphics library, and will run in most browsers, on both the PC and the Mac. Support for Linux should be available "soon" (Microsoft and Intel are apparently working on it). In the mean time, there's Mono and Moonlight.

From a game application perspective, Silverlight is nice because it supports things like timelines and animation. Plus, being able to separate markup from code helps keep the design clean and manageable.

Comment: interesting, a vote for C#... thanks for the advice! I don't know much about the language, but there's no time like the present to learn!

Comment: Another possibility would be F#. It's still a .NET language, so you can still leverage the full depth of the .NET Framework (libraries) and associated tools.

Comment: why F#? What do I gain from using this language?

Comment: F# is Microsoft's entry in the functional language arena (derived from ML and OCaml). Compared to C#, you gain easier representation of data flow, parallelism and async operations, as well as strong typing that's based on deep type inference.  Compared to non-.NET languages, you gain access to the .NET Framework and the Silverlight deploy-and-run mechanisms (which include being able to store data on disk on the client side; something JavaScript doesn't have), and full support in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, if you're teaching programming, you may also want to make sure the language has a good development environment -- a context sensitive editor and a powerful, easy-to-use debugger are very helpful.  Chances are that first time programmers are going to make lots of little mistakes and being able to easily step through lines of code and view variables and debug is as important in learning how to really program as all the theoretical parts such as using lambda functions.

Comment: hrm... "nice" debuggers always seemed to make things more difficult for me. I'm not entirely convinced by your development environment argument... but I'm most assuredly not a skilled pedagogue. Personally I'd rather go for a language that is very high level, to keep syntax issues to a minimum, but I will definitely think hard about your suggestion!

Comment: Even though this answer doesn't address the question in the OP, I agree with what Adisak is saying. I think you will find that having a strong development environment is an invaluable teaching (and learning) aid.

Comment: Hrm... two votes, I must consider this more carefully. I myself never used a very strong development environment, I just had syntax highlighting and a rather standard debugger... thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: I just mention this because if the game playing code is not trivial, a beginner programmer may spend more time fixing syntax errors and trying to debug their code than they spend on the initial design.  Even if the code "functions" (runs with valid outputs), they may want to spend time analyzing and tweaking the algorithm to more optimally play the game.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered C++, it keeps it simple. You could have a 'CORE' thats a binary and then just get your students to compile libraries that the C++ file calls, that way each student can submit a folder with all the different library and all you would have to do is move the binary to the folder and run it. The binary would use their libraries to execute the different aspects of the code you wanted to make modular.

This approach has the added effect of teaching them how to work in teams too, you could have one person write the render subsystem, another the input subsystem, etc. And all you would have to define in your binary is a set of skeleton functions that you call to do the logic for those sections.

Comment: C++ unfortunately is a poor pedagogical language, though I like your approach. Also I'd have to do function pointers which would make things remarkably difficult. I think your team idea is of great pedagogical value though!

Comment: The concepts can be ported to any OOP language that support libraries of any kind. If you need to do function pointers, just do it within the libraries. 

The binary core should just be a system initiator and loader, so no real _work_ should be done within it. Out of curiosity, what grade is this for?

Comment: Good question! Forgot to mention that. It's directed at high school, but I would hope to extend it eventually to middle school level. Here's my issue with function pointers though, I need to allow the user to create functions for the cards, and functions for the rules of the game. So I'm curious, is it possible to create objects which can accept functions declared in a library? So, if I was playing a game such that when a card was played it must take account of the cards in play and performs an action with regards to them, could that action be stated as a function and attached?

Comment: Im not 100% sure i understand your question completely; if your asking if its possible to declare your card structure in one library and to utilize it in another, i don't believe so. You may have to define it within your binary, however you can call methods of that object from within your classes. For example, you can have the CARD class in a library accessed from within another library, the only issue is that library (2) would need to reference library (1) within itself.

Comment: No problem, I'm not phrasing the question well. I'll try again. The simplest way to state it is, can an object take a function as a value? So, could Card.function = aFunctionPointer work?